# What is the difference between \eqref and \ref?

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

Is there any difference between `\eqref` and `\ref`? I used both of them in my document using the package `classicthesis` and saw no difference in the result. Is there any specific situation in which I should use `\eqref` or `\ref`?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The command `\ref` is defined in the LaTeX Kernel. The command `\eqref` is defined by `amsmath`. In the [documentation of `amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) you will find the explanation in section 3.11.2 *Cross references to equation numbers*.

`\eqref` puts brackets around the reference number. It's also places the references in in `\upshape` (or `\textup`), to match the equation reference exactly (Thanks to Werner). This is shown in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\verb+\eqref{eq:1} vs \ref{eq:1}+: \eqref{eq:1} vs \ref{eq:1}

\verb+\textit{\eqref{eq:1} vs \ref{eq:1}}+: \textit{\eqref{eq:1} vs \ref{eq:1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you use the package `classicthesis`, you must load `amsmath` before. Because the package `classicthesis` loads the package `hyperref`. However the package itself doesn't change the format of the output.