# Put parentheses by default when referencing an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, punctuation, labels

I have this equation:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:helicsol}
    x = y
\end{equation}
```

and then I have:

```
As we can observe, the solution of \ref{eq:helicsol}
```

and I get:

```
As we can observe, the solution of 2
```

since this is the second equation in my document. So, I could put parentheses manually, but I would like this to happen automatically, because the equation environment will put parentheses automatically when displaying `x = y`.

Comment: with `amsmath`, use `\eqref{...}`.  see [What is the difference between \eqref and \ref?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107422/579).

Comment: That's it @barbarabeeton, I did not know it. Are you going to post this as an answer? Oh you mean a duplicate? I could not find that if this is the case.

Comment: Well @barbarabeeton how would a simple user like me find the other question, since it contains `\eqref` in its title? :) I think my question is not that bad and an answer would be nice.

Comment: @G.Samaras: Closing this question as a duplicate of another doesn't mean it will go away. It will remain here for future visitors (since it has a non-zero score) and they will find the duplicate from here. Your post will guide as a stepping-stone.

Comment: Oh yeah @Werner, I am voting this to close then. :)