# What is the correct way to type "See Eq. (n)

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a document with equations and I am used to refer to equations with `\eqref{label}`.

However if I want to refer to it in a commentary with parenthesis `(see Eq. \eqref{label})`, it will make double parenthesis, which is not nice I guess.

I was expecting something like the \cite command which allows for including extra words in it with `\citep[something before][something after]{label}` but it does not work.

Should I use `(see Eq. \ref{label})`or is this just sort of a hack and impropoer Latex typo ?

Comment: Maybe my `eqcite.sty`, found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103546/how-do-i-configure-a-ref-of-a-label-to-print-more-than-just-the-number/103553#103553, might help.  You can customize it to give the words you want.

Comment: Remember you can use commas instead of parentheses, see Eq. \eqref{lable}, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon @Alenanno and also including optional arguments for @Steven commands an answer with the more advanced `\NewDocumentCommand` from package `xparse`:

```
\LetLtxMacro{\oldeqref}{\eqref}
\RenewDocumentCommand\eqref{D<>{Eq.}om}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
{#1~\oldeqref{#3}}
{(#2 #1~\textup{\ref{#3}})}%
}
```

will do the job, that is:`\eqref` is unchanged but `\eqref[something]{label}` returns `(Something n)` and it is also possible to change the base word Eq. (in my example) with `\eqref<eqn>{label}` and `\eqref<eqn>[Something]{label}`:

**Example**

```
\eqref{eq:label}; \eqref[Before]{eq:label}; \eqref<eqn>{eq:label}; \eqref<eqn>[Before]{eq:label}
```

**Output**

[image: output new eqref]

Answer (score 2):

I just use `\ref{eq_my_equation}` in all cases, as the parentheses around equation numbers aren't necessary in what I write.  You could do the same, or just use `\ref` when required.

Note that (from an answer to [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107422/28808)) `amsmath`'s `\eqref` also sets the equation number in the relevant upright font.  We could get into a discussion about whether or not that's the right thing to do, but for the purposes of this answer: I've never had to deal with this problem, having never had to refer to an equation from within italics.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think this is the ideal solution, you can redefine the command `\eqref`, because this means that it will change it for the whole document. If you don't want this, just define a different command.

If you want to define a new command, just write:

```
\newcommand\myeqref[1]{
    (see Eq. \textup{\ref{#1}})
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{(see Eq. \textup{\ref{#1}})}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

If I refer to the equation, it does it all by itself, here: \eqref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what does `\textup` do ? About redefining `\eqref` it is not an issue with `\NewDocumentCommand` as it is possible to modify only the behaviour if optional argument is provided

Comment: @clemlaflemme The original command `\eqref` is enclosed in `\textup`, which basically disallows the reference to not be "italic". Try writing `\textit{\eqref{eq:1}}`, the `1` will stay regular. Maybe you can enclose the whole reference in it, so if you have italic text, the reference will stay up.

Comment: @Alenanno No love for a non-breaking space after Eq.? ;)

Comment: @Jon you mean with ~? Sure,  I'll fix it when I get back to my computer :P