# change \eqref format with \RenewDocumentCommand (or other way)

Tags: cross-referencing

This is a follow on for an answer in:
[What is the correct way to type "See Eq. (n)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306401/what-is-the-correct-way-to-type-see-eq-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}   

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}    
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\LetLtxMacro{\oldeqref}{\eqref}
\RenewDocumentCommand\eqref{D<>{Equation}om}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}
{#1~\oldeqref{#3}}
{(#2 #1~\textup{\ref{#3}})}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
x=2y;
\end{equation}%

what this looks like:

this is Equation~\eqref{eq:test}

this is \eqref[Equation]{eq:test}

%this is \eqref[Equation][: terms 1 and 2]{eq:test}



\end{document}
```

This answer does most of what I want to do, but I would like to change it so that

```
 \eqref[]{eqlable}
```

can also take the form

```
\eqref[][]{eqlabel}
```

so that writing can be added both before and after the equation number within the brackets. Also, I would like to not have the "Equation" in there as I've already written this throughout my document (when I don't need brackets) and adding this doubles it. If I delete this from the above - I end up with a weird space.

Defining a new command would also work - and I have seen other answers based on this - but I don't know how to edit any of them to get the before and after text working.

edit: I would like the second option to look something like

```
   \eqref[Equation][: terms 1 and 2]{eqlabel}
```

and to produce (Equation 1.1: terms 1 and 2). The brackets already get automatically added when I type [] as an option.

and for

```
Equation~\eqref{eqlabel}
```

to produce Equation (1.1). This already works

any way to get the terms: 1 and 2 after the number in the bracket would be fine. i can change how i write Equation to match whatever works

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable? If there's only one optional argument, what should be done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's working as you want :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}   

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}    
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


%\LetLtxMacro{\oldeqref}{\eqref}
% As Christian Hupfer noted, there is no need to use \LetLtxMacro here. Although there is no harm is using it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro)
\let\oldeqref\eqref
\RenewDocumentCommand\eqref{oom}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\def\eqafter{}}{\def\eqafter{#2}}%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}
{\oldeqref{#3}}
{(#1 \textup{\ref{#3}}\eqafter)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test}
x=2y;
\end{equation}%

what this looks like:

this is Equation~\eqref{eq:test}

this is \eqref[Equation]{eq:test}

this is \eqref[Equation][: terms 1 and 2]{eq:test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `\eqref` does not have an optional argument, so no need for `\LetLtxMacro` -- an ordinary `\let` should suffice