# Automatically encase a cross-referenced equation number in round parentheses

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to customise the way `\ref` command appears on my output.
When i use the `\ref{reference_to_something}` to some equation, the outcome is the number of the equation, or the definition with the label "reference_to_something", but I want it to appear between round parentheses. For instance if I have:

> and referring to equation 4.3.2 [...]

my purpose is to add, automatically, without writing every time `()`,

> and referring to equation (4.3.2) [...]

I tried with `\renewcommand` but it did not work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For equations, you can use `\eqref` from [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. So, instead of `\ref{reference_to_something}`, you write `\eqref{reference_to_something}` and get `(equation_number)`.

Comment: With `\cref` (from cleveref) you even don't have to type ‘equation’…

Comment: Interesting package. Does it support the match of reference exactly like `\eqref` does (does not alter font shape in e.g. italic text, like in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107425/93555))?

Comment: `\cref` did not worked for me... `\eqref` is an interesting solution! That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A solution without any further packages, by redefinition of `\p@equation`, which 'gobbles' `\csname theequation\endcsname` first (the usual cross-reference format) and then uses `(\theequation)`  -- this requires `\def`in order to make use of the `\csname theequation\endcsname` as an argument delimiter -- `\newcommand` would not work here.
Since `@` is involved,  a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is needed in a normal document file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\gobblesomething#1\csname theequation\endcsname{(\theequation)}
\renewcommand{\p@equation}{\gobblesomething}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{17}

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^{2} \label{Einstein}
\end{equation}

See \ref{Einstein}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407421/31729

And another similar question can be found here about gobbling some text: [Reference appendix objects within texts as 'A. 1', but not 'Appendix A. 1'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413002/reference-appendix-objects-within-texts-as-a-1-but-not-appendix-a-1)

Comment: My vote for the friends is fast :-). +1