# Superscript cross references to an appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I'm writing a report and I'd like to use superscript references (like I'm already using for the bibliography) to link to a section withing an `\appendix` so it appears as a superscript with brackets like [A.1] or [A.2] (to match the section I'm pointing).

All I've been able to do is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%a million other packages

\begin{document}

Text see annex 1\ref{ref:a}

\appendix
\section{title of annex}
information\label{ref:a}

\end{document}
```

This works well enough, except it only displays an A without brackets with the same size as the text. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397724/31729, for example, but the term `superscript` is misleading, here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why do say "superscript" is misleading, if the OP wants superscripts?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Superscript is something like `x^{2}` for me ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Indeed I'd like them also to be superscripted, I've updated the question to make it more clear. Anyway thanks for the brackets, that's already a step in the right direction.

Comment: @salhelder: It was a waste of time for me to answer a question that was posted and changed afterwards :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just made it more clear, but I figured it out, you have my eternal gratitude, granted it ain't much. I just had to change the line to:
        \textsuperscript{[A.\thesection]}}%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross -reference format is stored for a counter, named, say foo, as as `\p@foo\csname thefoo\endcsname`, basically always `\p@foo` is empty, and `\thefoo` comes into action. The storage occurs in `\refstepcounter` as `\@currentlabel`.

Defining `\p@foo` as `[]` will only print `[]` before `\thefoo`, but not enclose it. `\csname thefoo\endcsname` has to 'gobbled' (captured with a special macro using it as delimiter, then `[A.\thefoo]` can be used.

In order to limit this effect to the appendix only, I've added it to the definition of `\appendix` with `\g@addto@macro{\appendix}`.

In my explanations replace `foo` with `section`, however.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%a million other packages

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%
  \def\@gobblerefstuff#1\csname thesection\endcsname{%
    [A.\thesection]}%
  \renewcommand{\p@section}{\@gobblerefstuff}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text see annex \ref{ref:a} or \ref{Completelydifferent}



\appendix
\section{title of annex}
information\label{ref:a}

\section{And now for something completely different} \label{Completelydifferent}

\end{document}
```

[image]