# Change the equation reference style

Tags: numbering, equation-number

I'm writing my undergraduate thesis and right now when I refer to an equation in the text the number of the equation is shown without the parenthesis. While in the equation itself the number is shown with parenthesis, as is in the following print.

[image: print of how my text is now]

But I need them both to be shown equally (with or without parenthesis in both). I've tried to use the following command,

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation})}
```

but the result was not as desired, because as shown in the following print now in the text the number have parenthesis, but the equation now have two parentheses.

[image: result not desired]

So there is any alternative? I've seen about the package cleveref, but I have many reference to equations and would be good if it was possible to do something less exhaustive than change every reference.

Comment: Does `\eqref` from `amsmath` meet your needs? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107422/106162

Comment: @DaiBowen yes, meets perfectly. But it is possible to me to use it without need to change every \ref in my text, one by one?

Comment: If you use `\ef` only for equations, it may be possible to redefine it, but if you have cross references to anything else, like a section or theorem, that would likely be too complicated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well in this work in particular have only one figure beside the equations. But I've already handle the problem using ctrl+F and replacing every ref occurrence and now I have to fix what wasn't a \ref, because I'm running out of time. But would be good if it was possible to implement, if helps, every label for equation I start with 'eq:', for figures 'fig:' and for tables 'tab:'.

Comment: @GabrielMarino -- I think this would more easily and reliably be addressed by a good editor, since you apparently have enough other instances of `\ref` to be a problem.  If the equation references are consistently and reliably entered as `\ref{eq:`, a global replace of that string by `\eqref{eq:` should not only produce the result you want, but also avoid rather complicated command redefinitions as well as leaving you with a source that says exactly what you want.